# checking my understanding of pointers/structures and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, typedef

Hey all I'm just trying to understand a few key concepts, and have done my own research but have a few questions and would really appreciate it if someone could check to see if they're correct. I'm doing a review for a test, and our professor told us to figure it out ourselves...so i did and here it goes :)

**1: declare a pointer called thePointer to hold the address of an element from an array with 10 elements called Pointed**

```
int Pointed[10] = {};

int *thePointer = &Pointed[1];
```

Need help with this one...

**2: write a function that will accept the address of an array and number of elements in an array and use information to initialize each element of array to zero**

```
void arrayFunction (int *array, int element)

    for (x = 0; x < element; x++);
      {
      array[x] = 0;
      }
```

**3: create a structure that holds bits representing the following**

**--2 fields that each hold 4bit BCD digits, together they hold current rotation count (i called them CRC1 and CRC2)
motor direction: 2 bits
speed: 4 bits
fault condition: 3 bits
Name the structure controlMotor**

```
struct controlMotor{

unsigned char CRC1: 4;
unsigned char CRC2: 4;
unsigned int motorDirection: 2;
unsigned int speed: 4;
unsigned int faultCondition: 3;
};
```

**-- use typedef to name this new data type: statusDrive_t**

```
typedef controlMotor statusDrive_t;
```

**--create array of structure named marsDrive to hold status of each 6 drives**

```
statusDrive_t marsDrive[5] ={statusDrive_t.CRC1,statusDrive_t.CRC2,statusDrive_t.motorDirection,statusDrive_t.speed,statusDrive_t.faultCondition}
```

**initialize each field of the first element of array with maximum value**

```
marsDrive[0].CRC1 = 15;
marsDrive[0].CRC2 = 15;
```

Comment: Try to ask only one question at once. Or if you have few follow up questions, than try to keep it cohesive at least (as related as possible).

Comment: I think you missed the point of #2

Comment: Concur with Mike. You may consider a different opening for #2, something along the lines of `void arrayFunction(int arr[], size_t n)`

Comment: In addition to Mike's comment, you can's use *arrayIndex <= numElements* as you do for #2. The last iteration of the loop will try to access an element that's not part of the array. Remember, a 10 element array will have it's indexes in the range [0..9]. Therefore, you need to use *arrayIndex < numElements*

Comment: Closing as not a real question since it's several questions delimited by a homework assignment.

Comment: not a homework assignment, but if you believe so that's up to you....it's a test review posted online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 looks fine, but you don't need the `&` operator just:

```
int *thePointer = Pointed;
```

will work because arrays decay into pointers.

2 `write a function that will accept the address of an array and number of elements in an array` Your function takes only an `int` that's not even close to what the question was asking. The point this question is trying to make you reference is that passing an array to a function loses the information as to the number of elements in the array.

I'm pretty sure they were looking for something more like:

```
void arrayFunction (int * arr, int elements) // you could do (int arr[], ... as well 
{
    for(int i = 0; i<elements; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int i[4];
    arrayFunction(i, 4);
```

3 Your typedef is wrong, it should be:

```
typedef struct controlMotor statusDrive_t;
```

the syntax is:

```
typedef <the type> <the new name to call it>;
```

And in this case the type is `struct controlMotor`

The array is declared incorrectly as well. `int marsDrive[6]` that makes an array of `int`s. You want to put the type before the array, so in this case since you just made that fancy new typedef:

```
statusDrive_t marsDrive[6];
```

Will give you an array of 6 struct controlMotor's (numbered 0 to 5). And for the last part of 3: `initialize each field of the first element of array with maximum value` you need to initialize the fields of the first element. That's done by:

```
marsDrive[0].CRC1 = ...
marsDrive[0].CRC2 = ...
```

When you increment that value in the `[]` you're moving away from the first element. You can figure out the "max" size of each by the number of bits. For example CRC1 is 4 bits, that means the most you can have is 1111<sub>2</sub> which is 15<sub>10</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Mike, especially relating to Q2 and Q3...very good point about the value of the element

Comment: @mike : `...Will give you an array of 5 struct controlMotor's` is wrong. 6 represents the no. of elements of an array, whose index start from 0 to 5

Comment: @cipher - yup, my bad, typing too quickly

Answer (score 2):

**Q1: If the question was to point to *any* element of array, you are correct. But 1 is not a first element of array.**

**Q2: The function should accept the address of the array, you are declaring the array inside the function. Also, the semi-colon after the `for` should be avoided. Also, you should only use < instead of <= .  The correct one should be like:**

```
void ArrayFunction(int arr[], int i) {
for (x = 0; x < i; x++){
      arr[x] = 0;
      }
}
```

**I think Q3 is good but the typedef should be**

```
typedef struct controlMotor statusDrive_t;
```

**Also the array must be declared as**

```
statusDrive_t marsDrive[6];
```

**And arrays start from 0 (to 5 in your case)**

Comment: thanks for the reply! seems like i royally screwed up on question 2, but thank you nonetheless! as for the other question I have changed it up, please let me know if it is correct now (Q3)

Comment: your typedef is still wrong. 
Declare arrays just as i wrote in my answers. anything after `=` is not required.
`statusDrive_t marsDrive[5]` creates an array with **five** elements whose index start from 0 to 4 . So, you should use `statusDrive_t marsDrive[6]'

Also, **initialize each field of first element of arrray** may mean to initialize the value of first structure in the array. Do something like:

marsDrive[0].CRC1=.....
marsDrive[0].CRC2=....
For each fields.